# Trouble Getting UITextViews to Adapt to content Using Auto-Layout while Embedded in UIScrollView

Tags: swift, autolayout, uitextview

I'm attempting to create a scrollview with embedded UITextViews.  I plan to change the content of the UITextView at runtime.  I'm having problems getting the desired effect of my layout using Auto-Layout.

I'd like the UITextViews to wrap at the trailing view.  And, push all the other UILabels and UITextViews down.  I've been able to get this to work in portrait alone, but when the device is rotated it becomes wonky.

I've disabled scrolling on both UITextViews, both in the Storyboard and code.

[image]

I've also added constraints outlets and attempted to change them in code using the `UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue` but I cannot seem to find a combination of constraints which will create my desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this would be to use a static UITableView.

I showed an example of how to do this with code and screenshots on my blog.

http://www.oliverfoggin.com/using-a-static-uitableview-as-a-layout-device/

Comment: Thank you--that seems much cleaner.